# Input in hex or ASCII, but ensure output in ASCII?

Tags: c#, xml, ascii, hex

I am trying reading in data from XML files using C# XMLTextReader. Most of the data I am reading in comes in as ASCII, however there are a few values that come in as hex.

To read the data I am using the following line of code:

```
string PIDData = reader.ReadElementString();
Console.WriteLine("Value: " + PIDData);
```

So when PIDData is in hex the output is in hex.

How can I perform a test to see if the value is hex or ASCII and perform the conversion if it is hex?

Comment: how can you tell if it is in hex when it's read by a person?

Comment: Sounds like incorrect values were inserted into the xml document.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that some of the data in the XML is in the wrong format,  but it's diagnosic data being read from an embedded device, so I need to work with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a string that contains the value...

```
BEEF
```

...would you classify this as ASCII or hex?

You can't - it could be either.

Comment: or 'FED A BAD DAF' (sorry, couldn't think of real word instead of the last one)

Comment: Ahh, yes, I see your point there. I'm not too sure of the correct terminology to use. By hex I meant 41 42 43 rather than ABC ASCII.

Comment: You might have a chance if the hex data is prefixed with something like 0x... as in "0xDEADBEEF".  It's still "ASCII", but you could make the assumption and treat it as a hex string.

Comment: I realise what you are saying, I think I am going to need to think about the problem a different way.